# Syntax to store results of previous mapping

Tags: project-reactor

I would like to know the good way to use results of previous mapping in spring web-flux, for example

```
Mono.just(request)
...
.flatMap(object0 -> createObject1(object0))
.flatMap(object1 -> createObject2(object1))
...
```

what a good way to get object0 at this point, so we could add something like

```
.flatmap(object0 -> createResult(object0))
```

I solved it by uniting this both method so that we have object0 in global variable, but it doesn't looks good.

Another example

```
Mono.just(request)
...
.flatMap(object0 -> createResponse(object))
.map(result -> mapToObject1(result))
.flatMap(object1-> saveObject1(object1))
```

How to return "result" at this point?

Could you please give link to good example of same cases, because solution to unite this line to make result global doesn't looks good as it creates ambiguous methods?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can wrap several objects into a `reactor.util.function.Tuples`, like this:

```
Mono.just(request)
...
.flatMap(object0 -> Tuples.of(object0, createObject1(object0)))
.flatMap(tuple -> createObject2(tuple.getT2()))
...
```

I don't know if it's really a best practice here, because your code snippet is very generic and I can't say whether it's an issue with the underlying API.

Comment: I think an operator similar to several flatmap chain returning all elements from initial to the end flatmap of the chain would be very helpfull (like this library does https://github.com/pakoito/Komprehensions)

Answer (score 4):

For the first case, because you are using `flatMap` for `createObject1(object0)`, I assume that it is returning `Mono<Object1>` , I think the following code snippet can do what you wanted.

```
    public Mono<Class1> createObject1(Class0 object0) {
        //...
    }

    public Mono<Class2> createObject2(Class1 object1, Class0 object0) {
        //...
    }

    public void test() {
        Mono.just(new Class0())
        .flatMap(object0 -> createObject1(object0).zipWith(Mono.just(object0)))
        .flatMap(tuple -> createObject2(tuple.getT1(), tuple.getT2()));
    }
```

For the second case, as the accepted answer suggested, using `reactor.util.function.Tuples` in `map` will do.

Answer (score 0):

My version looks like that

```
.flatMap(upperResult -> {
    return Mono.just(upperResult).zipWith(monoGeneratingFunction(upperResult));
})
.flatMap(tuple -> {
    var upperResult = tuple.getT1();
    var lowerResult = tuple.getT2();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zipWhen` with straight on the mono. `zipWhen` is a specific operator that combines results.

```
Mono.just(request)
...
.zipWhen(object0 -> createObject1(object0))
...
```